# Calculating spring constant

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, spring

We have a vertical spring positioned on the moon. When compressed by $17m$, this spring sends $1500kg$ packages into escape velocity $(2400m/s)$, and then back to Earth. What is the spring constant?

I know that the initial energy is all elastic potential, given by $\frac{1}{2}kx_1^{2}$, where $x_1$ is the initial compressed position. (We take $x=0$ to be the equilibrium position).

Question: when will the package actually leave the spring? Do I have to factor in the gravitational potential energy gained from the initial position to the final position? For example,
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2}kx_1^2 = \frac{1}{2}kx_2^2+\frac{1}{2}mv^2+mgh
\end{align*}
where $x_2$ is the position of the spring once the package is moving at escape velocity, and $h$ is the distance from $x_1$ to $x_2$. If so, how do I get this $x_2$?

Will the package leave the spring at $x = 0$?

Comment: Little confused about the question. Doesn't the package leave the spring when the spring is fully extended after being released from its compressed position? f I would think the equilibrium position of the spring is when it is fully extended, and the compressed initial position is 17 meters. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: How can I find the $x_2$ at which the spring full extends? It can't be that $\lvert x_1 \rvert = \lvert x_2 \rvert$, since the object is doing work on the spring as it is decompressing and extending again. My problem is, I think the kinetic energy corresponding to the escape velocity occurs once the object leaves the spring, and so we cannot neglect the work the object is doing on the spring. And so, the initial elastic potential energy should equal the kinetic, gravitational and elastic potential energies when the package finally leaves the spring. Is this thinking incorrect?